# Alias not working when calling bash.exe -l -c "alias_name" from cmd

Tags: python, bash, shell, cmd, cygwin

I am using cygwin and I have added in .bashrc and .bash_profile the alias
python3 pointing to my python 3.8.9 local instalation path:

```
alias python3=/cygdrive/c/Python38/python.exe
```

Now, when I open cygwin and type:

```
python3 --version
Python 3.8.9
```

But if I run the command in windows cmd:

```
C:/cygwin64/bin/bash.exe -l -c 'python3 --version'
Python 3.8.10 (this version is that installed inside cygwin)
```

A very strange thing is when i type in cmd:

```
C:/cygwin64/bin/bash.exe -l -c 'alias'
alias python3=/cygdrive/c/Python38/python.exe
```

So, the alias is being loaded in both cases (cygwin and cmd bash.exe call) but is not being applied for the second case.

What can be done to solve this?

EDIT:

Another tests I did:

On cygwin (prints 'OK'):

```
alias test='echo OK'; alias; test;

alias /cygdrive/c/Python38/python.exe

alias test='echo OK'
OK
```

On Windows cmd (not printing 'OK'):

```
c:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe -l -c "alias test='echo OK'; alias; test;"

alias /cygdrive/c/Python38/python.exe

alias test='echo OK'
```

Comment: If I change the alias to anything still got the same result in the second case

Comment: The alias is *defined*, but alias *expansion* is disabled by default in non-interactive shells, which is what `bash -c` starts. Alias expansion also occurs when a line of input is read, which is before your alias is actually defined in your last example.

Comment: Thanks forthe answer it makes sense to me. And how do I enable this alias expansion?

Comment: Look at your environnement ***when open cygwin***. Simply hit `set` without argiment. This will dump your whole current environment. so you could ensure: *U are using bash*, which kind of version and so on....

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to chepner, I found the command to expand the alias to non interactive shells:

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
```

I put in the .bashrc and .bash_profile files and its is working fine now

Comment: Not necessarily. `.bash_profile` is processed in non-interactive shells only, if `bash` is invoke with the `--login` option. `.bashrc` is nevre processe in non-interactive shells. See the bash man page, section _INVOCATION_.